# Convergent series to the power of a natural even numbers

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, power-series

I really can't find the right approach to solve this question. I've tried all tests, but I'm stuck. Any hint?

Knowing that $(a_n)_{n \geq 1}$ is a real numbers convergent series and $(k_n)_{n \geq 1}$ is a even natural numbers sequence such that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n^{k_n}$ is convergent, prove that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n^{k_{n+\alpha}}$ converges for any $\alpha \geq 0$.

Comment: Hint: The absolute value of your first sequence has to be $<1$ for big $n$.

Comment: Oh, of course! If it isn't < 1 the first series won't converge! Thank you!